# Woocommerce Create Order REST API and Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin.forms, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a checkout page written in Xamarin Forms that creates an order in Woocommerce.

I've looked up documentation online but can't seem to find any examples or code that shows you how to do this.

My question is : is there an example code on how to create a simple order using Xamarin Forms and Woocommerce REST API?

I was able to use the REST API to pull the products from Woocommerce but can't seem to find any code examples of how to actually create an order using the REST API in Xamarin Forms.

Hope you can help.

Cheers

Here's my code woocommerceapi.cs class.

```
class WoocommerceAPI
    {
        private static string website_url = "xxxxx";
        private static string consumer_key = "xxxxx";
        private static string consumer_secret = "xxxxx";

        private static string GetAllProductsApiUrl = string.Format("{0}/wc-api/v3/products?consumer_key={1}&consumer_secret={2}", website_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret);

        private static string GetAllProductsInACategoryApiUrl = "xxxxx/wc-api/v3/products?category=379&consumer_key=xxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxx";

        public async Task<Products> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetAllProductsApiUrl);
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(json);
            return products;
        }

        public async Task<Products> GetAllProductsInACategory()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetAllProductsInACategoryApiUrl);
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(json);
            return products;
        }

    }
```

Comment: there is a .NET client - https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET

Comment: Thanks for that, that was really helpful! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build a solution and it's now working!

Here's the code if you come across this problem and need a fix.

```
async void OrderBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   
            Console.WriteLine("Starting REST API");

            var clientapi = new HttpClient();

            clientapi = new Uri("xxxx?consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting REST API");

            var clientapi = new HttpClient();

            clientapi.BaseAddress = new Uri("xxxx?consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx");

            // json data for adding customer
            string jsonData = @"{
                                ""first_name"" : ""John1"",
                                ""last_name"" : ""Doe1"",
                                ""email"" : ""john.doe1@example.com"",
                                ""username"" : ""john.doe1"",
                                ""password"" : ""mypassword"",
                                ""billing"": {
                                        ""first_name"": ""John"",
                                        ""last_name"": ""Doe"",
                                        ""company"": ""john doe company"",
                                        ""address_1"": ""969 Market"",
                                        ""address_2"": """",
                                        ""city"": ""San Francisco"",
                                        ""state"": ""CA"",
                                        ""postcode"": ""94103"",
                                        ""country"": ""US"",
                                        ""email"": ""john.doe@example.com"",
                                        ""phone"": ""(555) 555-5555""
                                    },
                                    ""shipping"": {
                                        ""first_name"": ""John"",
                                        ""last_name"": ""Doe"",
                                        ""company"": """",
                                        ""address_1"": ""969 Market"",
                                        ""address_2"": """",
                                        ""city"": ""San Francisco"",
                                        ""state"": ""CA"",
                                        ""postcode"": ""94103"",
                                        ""country"": ""US""
                                    }

                                }";

            Console.WriteLine("Here's the json string data");
            Console.WriteLine(jsonData);

            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage apiresponse = await clientapi.PostAsync("xxxxx?consumer_key=xxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx", content);

            var apiresult = await apiresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Here's the result:");

            Console.WriteLine(apiresult);

            Console.WriteLine("REST API Post Completed.");

            await DisplayAlert("Checkout", "Completed", "ok");

        }
```

Obviously you can setup public variables to store the json data and you're more than welcome to do so, i'm not your dad.